# How to generate co-occurence datatable using either Spark SQL, Pyspark or R spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a co-occurrence matrix from some **very large** dataset that looks like below:

| ID | Preference |
| --- | --- |
| 1001 | choice 1 |
| 1001 | choice 2 |
| 2001 | choice 1 |
| 2001 | choice 2 |
| 2001 | choice 3 |
| 2002 | choice 4 |

Co-occurence (by ID):

| Choices | Choices With | N |
| --- | --- | --- |
| choice 1 | choice 2 | 2 |
| choice 1 | choice 3 | 1 |
| choice 2 | choice 3 | 1 |
| choice 1 | choice 4 | 0 |
| choice 2 | choice 4 | 0 |
| choice 3 | choice 4 | 0 |

Thanks, all!

Answer (score 1):

Here is one, rather brute-ish, way to make it happen:

1. Create a test dataframe:

   ```
    t = spark.createDataFrame([(1001,"choice 1"),(1001,"choice 2"),(2001,"choice 1"),(2001,"choice 2"),(2001,"choice 3"),(2002,"choice 4")],["id", "pref"])
   ```
2. Make a dataframe of all possible combinations

   ```
    dft = t.select("pref").distinct()
    dfp = dft.withColumnRenamed("pref","pref1").join(dft.withColumnRenamed("pref","pref2")).filter("pref1 < pref2")
    dfp.show(truncate=False)
    +--------+--------+
    |pref1   |pref2   |
    +--------+--------+
    |choice 1|choice 2|
    |choice 1|choice 4|
    |choice 1|choice 3|
    |choice 2|choice 4|
    |choice 2|choice 3|
    |choice 3|choice 4|
    +--------+--------+
   ```
3. Create a dataframe of combinations that exist in test data

   ```
    dft = t.withColumnRenamed("pref","pref1").join(t.withColumnRenamed("pref","pref2"),"id")
    dff = dft.filter("pref1 < pref2")
    dff.show(truncate=False)
    +----+--------+--------+
    |id  |pref1   |pref2   |
    +----+--------+--------+
    |1001|choice 1|choice 2|
    |2001|choice 1|choice 2|
    |2001|choice 1|choice 3|
    |2001|choice 2|choice 3|
    +----+--------+--------+
   ```
4. Join both dataframes and aggregate to get a count

   ```
    from pyspark.sql.functions import *
    dfx = dfp.join(dff,["pref1","pref2"],"left").withColumn("x",when(col("id").isNull(),0).otherwise(1)).drop("id")
    dfx.groupBy("pref1","pref2").sum("x").show(truncate=False)
    +--------+--------+------+
    |pref1   |pref2   |sum(x)|
    +--------+--------+------+
    |choice 1|choice 2|2     |
    |choice 1|choice 4|0     |
    |choice 1|choice 3|1     |
    |choice 2|choice 4|0     |
    |choice 2|choice 3|1     |
    |choice 3|choice 4|0     |
    +--------+--------+------+
   ```

Few assumptions in the above -- a) choices are unique per ID; b) the order of choices is not important; and c) the values of "choice" column are comparable.

Comment: Thanks mazaneicha - I ended up looking at basket analysis algorithms to speed things up, but appreciate the answer!

Comment: @Ofelia Would be very interested to know if you succeeded with association rules. Post an answer to your own question -- i'll upvote for sure! :))